# going from word to number as in keys in a phone using a dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have already done a through search before asking this question as I always do.  I am trying to do use a dictionary to go from a written word to each individual letters corresponding letter on a phone key board using a dictionary in python. This is easy to do without a dictionary, but using a dictionary although faster to code is quite confusing to me. Help would be appreciated. My code so far is

```
def phone (word):
    d = {'A''B''C':2,'D''E''F':3,'G''H''I':4,'J''K''L':5}
    for i in range (len(word)):
        word.split ()
        return d[word]
```

the word I am trying to use is 'ADGJ' just as a test.

my errors that I am getting:

```
 File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    phone('ADGJ')
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\pratice.py", line 195, in phone
    return d[word]
KeyError: 'ADGJ'
```

I have a key error I thought the word.split would take care of any issues but it doesn't. any suggestions?

thank you

I changed the code up a bit: I now have this:

```
def phone (word):
    d = {'A':2, 'B':3}
    word = word.split()
    return d[word]
```

but I get a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    phone ('ABABBAA')
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\pratice.py", line 194, in phone
    return d[word]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

the word I am using just consits of 'ABBABABA' just because that is all I have defined in my dictionary since this is a test of understanding.

I guess I still need something to make the connection for the dictionary function thing to work but still trying to figure out what that is...

Comment: The whole function is totally messed up. You don't understand how to use a function, a dictionary, a string, a return statement etc. Your problem is not the `KeyError` but the lack of basic programming fundamentals. You should read a good introductional tutorial!

Comment: awesome @septi, I would agree with you.  I  am  still learning, and awesome fact is I am  using one of those books. Just going to continue to take time in order to get the concept down. As I continue to make mistakes I will see what I am doing wrong and ultimately grow understanding... Until then do you have any advice on the current question?

Comment: Well, there are several problems to solve. I guess it's better to go on and fail a lot, like anyone of us did when we began programming ;-) Of course, your code can be fixed, or even made more simple (see Cybers solution) but this won't help you much. To become a good programmer, you have to figure out the solutions yourself. At least, most of them…

Comment: There you go @ChristopherJakob, I wrote a longer answer to you "problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid Python

```
d = {'A''B''C':2,'D''E''F':3,'G''H''I':4,'J''K''L':5}
```

You would need to define each key, value pair

```
d = {
     'A':2, 'B':2, 'C':2, 
     'D':3, 'E':3, ... etc
    }
```

You can then convert the word into the corresponding digits

```
def getNums(word):
    return ''.join(str(d[i]) for i in word)

>>> getNums('ADGJ')
'2345'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little off; you can't let assignment in a dictionary fall through like in a switch statement.

Try this:

```
d = {'A':2,'B':2,'C':2,'D':3,'E':3,'F':3,'G':4,'H':4,'I':4,'J':5,'K':5,'L':5}
```

Comment: I see  so the key is only to one statement always. I would then ask is that always the case? Is there a way around that? and thank you for taking the time to answer Killermonkey50 and @Cyber

Answer (score 1):

OK, so let me try to help you.

This is your current code:

```
def phone (word):
    d = {'A':2, 'B':3}
    word = word.split()
    return d[word]
```

The first line defines your function signature, that means you've got a function called `phone` which takes a parameter called `word`. My first comment is: chose appropriate names for functions and variables. `phone` is not a "function", since a function is kind of an instruction or a command like thing, but never mind (`letters_to_phonenumber` would be better I think).

The second line defines a dictionary, which maps `'A'` to `2`, `'B'` to '3'. That's OK for now.

The third line overwrites your `word` variable with the return value of the `split()` function, which is a method of the `string` class. Let's look up the documentation for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`:
>   Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

Since you obviously did not define a `sep`(arator), we have to figure out what the function will do. Reading further says:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

So it will look for whitespace within your string. You don't know what a whitespace is? Let's google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

> In computer science, whitespace is any character or series of
>   whitespace characters that represent horizontal or vertical space in
>   typography. When rendered, a whitespace character does not correspond
>   to a visible mark, but typically does occupy an area on a page.

OK, now we know, that whitespace is like `space` or `tab` etc. A string like `"ABABBAA"` does not contain any whitespace, so `split()` will obviously return only a list with exactly one item in it: the input string itself.

Let's fire up the python interpreter to check this (this is a common way of debugging):

```
>>> 'ABABBAA'.split()
['ABABBAA']
```

The next line in your code is `return d[word]`. So the function terminates here and returns an output value, namely `d[word]`. But what is the value of `d[word]`? Well, `d` is a dictionary (with the keys 'A' and 'B') and you try to find the value of the key `['ABABBAA']`. But there is no such key in your dictionary `d`, let alone there is no way to create a key for a dictionary, since a key has to be a hashable object. What is a hashable object? Let's google: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

> hashable: An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never
>   changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() or **cmp**() method).
>   Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no
>   mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which
>   are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they
>   all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is
>   their id().

OK, so `'A'` would be hashable ;-) and any kind of number of string etc. but not a `list`, in this sense.

So what now? You have to find a way to somehow separate the letters in your input `word`. This can be easily done with slicing, or simply iterating over the string (in Python, strings are iterable):

```
for letter in word:
    # this loop will iterate over word and assign each of its letters to
    # the variable `letter`, which you can use in this scope
```

**But how do we actually return the phone number? This will not work:**

```
def phone (word):
    d = {'A':2, 'B':3}
    for letter in word:
        return d[letter]
```

Why? Because it will stop at the first letter and terminate the function (remember the return statement?).

The way to go is to collect all the numbers and when we're done, simply put all together and return them. This is a common way to handle such problems. We first initialise a list, which we can manipulate in each for-iteration:

```
def phone (word):
    d = {'A':2, 'B':3}
    digits = []
    for letter in word:
        digits.append(d[letter])
    return digits
```

Great! Looks better now:

```
>>> phone('ABA')
[2, 3, 2]
```

Now try to figure out how to return a real number instead of a list.

This is btw. kind of a basic workflow of a programmer. A lot of research and look-up in (API) documentation, solving puzzles and looking at few lines of code hours long. If you don't love it, you'll never become a programmer.

Comment: GREATLY APPREICATED THANK YOU VERY MUCH.. YES I AM SHOUTING. i do enjoy this puzzle stuff. Fantastic. thank you